# How do I display top left 50x50 of an image with no resizing, only native resolution?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to make an animation with spritesheet (not using external libraries)

Currently trying to display the top left corner of an image (50 pixel by 50 pixel) on the center of my android screen

However, all I get is my original imaged resized to 50x50. How do I do this so that the original image is not resized, but only the top left corner 50x50 of that image?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review our [SO Question Checklist](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer. Please paste a minimal, complete, and verifiable example of the code you have already tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use [ImageEditor](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/imageeditor.html) which isn't external library, but a module provided by react native:
As you can see in following code, i crop from top-left corner(since offset for x and y is 0) and i crop 150x150 pixels, as specified in state.croppedWidth-croppedHeight:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Image, ImageEditor } from "react-native";

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      cropedPath: null,
      cropedWidth: 150,
      cropedHeight: 150,
      path:
        "https://blog.addthiscdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/01125908/200-200-pixels.png"
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.crop(this.state.path, this.state.cropedWidth, this.state.cropedHeight);
  }

  crop(path, cropedWidth, cropedHeight) {
    ImageEditor.cropImage(
      path,
      (cropData = {
        offset: { x: 0, y: 0 },
        size: { width: cropedWidth, height: cropedHeight },
        resizeMode: "cover"
      }),
      uri => this.setState({ cropedPath: uri }),
      error => console.log("error", error)
    );
  }

  loadImage(path, width, height) {
    return (
      <Image source={{ uri: path }} style={{ width: width, height: height }} />
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        {this.loadImage(this.state.path, 200, 200)}
        {this.loadImage(
          this.state.cropedPath,
          this.state.cropedWidth,
          this.state.cropedHeight
        )}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Screenshot after execution:
[image: croped image]